# Reading values in MATLAB and assigning coordinates to the entries

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, coordinates

I'm a bit new to MATLAB.

Basically, I have a 20x20 values , complete with various random entries ranging from 0 to 3. I need to write a program that reads this 20x20 square, and assigns x-y coordinates to the entries, so that when I ask for an input of a particular x-y coordinate which has, say an entry of 3, then it will result in an error.
I'm a bit overwhelmed - but I understand the general concept of what I'm supposed to be finding. I'm wondering if I should use a plot instead to help me.

Comment: Don't you already have coordinates assigned by definition if you have them in a matrix?  

`m(5,7)` will get you the x = 5, y = 7 entry in a 25x25 matrix named 'm'.

Comment: Oh; yep! But then would I have to go through every entries of '3' and check their coordinates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need all the x and y coordinates where there is a 3, you could use `find`:

```
[x,y] = find(m == 3)
```

for a matrix named 'm'.

There's more on find in matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/ref/find.html).